# jQuery Ajax always returning 404 Error ? Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here I have one quick basic question.Sorry if its very simple.
I executing jQuery ajax here. If i hit the server its returning 404.But it browser neIt's appearing as 503. I checked the jquery.min.js file.There they are checking the condition.I just want to return the actual error. Would it be possible ?

```
var server = '/getPeriodDropdown.htm';
var dataString = 'selected='+$(this).find('option:selected').val();
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : server,
   data : dataString,
   success : function(data) {
      alert("success");
  },
  error : function(error) {
     alert("error" + error);
  }
});
```

Now the doubt is in jQuery file

```
   "error"===e?r(s.status||404,s.statusText):r(mn[s.status]||s.status,s.statusText
```

Comment: getPeriodDropdown.htm wont return anything. You need to call a webservice

Comment: @JoakimM that's not true. Calling an html file will return the html source as a string value.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the jQuery file. [I try to send a request](http://jsfiddle.net/f3znybjk/) to a page, and get a 404 (successfully!?).

Comment: is **getPeriodDropdown.htm** in your website root location?

Comment: Now the URL doesn't a matter.If i hit the server with any valid url's Which is in some other domain , it returns 0 in browser.But in jQuery plugin they checking "s.status||404" , so it returns 404